# read byte array from C# that is written from Java

Tags: c#, java, arrays, endianness

I am trying to write an Integer from C# and read it from Java. An integer is 4 bytes in both languages. However when I write it from C#, integer 1 is written in the following bytes
1000. Meaning the first byte is 1 and the rest is 0.

But in Java the same thing is written as 0001. Meaing the first 3 bytes are 0 and the last is 1.

Is there a simple way of reading and writing among these languages instead of manually reversing every 4 byte?
The code for Java

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buffer.putInt(1);

for(byte b: buffer.array()){
      System.out.print(b);
}
```

The code for C#

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
{
    writer.Write((int)1);

}
foreach(byte b in ms.ToArray()){
    Console.Write(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this post points aus http://kirkwylie.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-binarywriter-is-little-endian-because.html C# BinaryWriter supports only little endian so you have to configure it on the java site with the order method http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29

Comment: Yes, you are right. C# doesn't support big endian. In my case, I should do all my changes on C# side. So I manually converted using    System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder

Answer (score 6):

You can switch the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) on either of the sides to make them compatible.

For example on java side, you can set it to use ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN (default is BIG_ENDIAN )

In your case you can use [ByteBuffer.order()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29) to set the order.

```
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

Or you can choose to change it on C# side in which case you'll have to make it Big-Endian to be compatible with java.