# What is the C# equivalent of Java's Integer.reverseBytes() method?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I have the following line of Java code:

```
Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.reverseBytes(dataInputStream.readInt()));
```

I want to do the same in C# and I have come up with the following code:

```
BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(binaryReader.ReadInt32()), 0)
```

This code is incomplete because I can't find any equivalent to Java's `Integer.reverseBytes`-Method. How can I translate this into C#?

Comment: ^^ especially mind MarkusSchaber's comment on the answer: _" the IPAddress class has static Methods to convert between host and network byte orders"_

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just read this question and according to this, Java stores Integers as Big Endian while C# uses Little Endian. Wouldn't that mean that my C# code is already correct since I reverse the bytes in Java? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952062/read-byte-array-from-c-sharp-that-is-written-from-java

Comment: Could be. You didn't include that in the question. But it's fairly easy to test that out, isn't it?

Comment: Btw: If you are working on communication between the two, I'd recommend to use a common representation instead of binary. Like JSON for example. Or something more efficient. Unless you have a good reason not to, of course. It has an overhead but then again, you don't have to deal with this kind of stuff.

Comment: If you're reading from a binary input, your best bet is probably to look at `BinaryPrimitives` - this has endian-specific read APIs, which means you can read it correctly in the endianness that you actually wanted

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the format of the data. I tested what I mentioned in my previous comment and it is true. Because C# uses little endian by default I don't have to reverse the bytes and can simply use `binaryReader.ReadSingle();`